# Is it possible to place an <img> element absolutely, using a <tr> as the parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a page which displays (summaries of) records in a database in a table. I'd like to display an icon to the left of each row, to visually 'flag' some records if they meet certain criteria.

Is it possible to place an `<img>` element absolutely, using the `<tr>` as the parent? (Or is there another way to achieve the same effect?)

```
echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $result['data'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

(I know to position an `<img>` absolutely I would simple use `position: absolute; top: 0; left: -20;` etc.)

Comment: Arr you trying to do with with PHP or CSS?

Comment: The PHP generates the HTML table. I am trying to use CSS to position the elements. I have an external style sheet, or I can include the CSS in the elements if that is somehow a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, position: relative on a table cell does not work in Firefox. So you would need to put a div inside the cell and give that relative positioning and its child absolute.

```
<td>
  <div style="position:relative">
      <img src="foo" style="position:absolute;" />  
  </div>
</td>
```

[Firefox bug reference](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168)

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a class for those special rows and use the `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements and mess with the positioning to get it right.

You could say something like:

```
.specialRow:before, .specialRow::before {
    content: url('imageURL.jpg');
    //set up positioning of the element
}
```

You may still need to do something like moettinger said to get the positioning just right, but I think using `:before` and `:after` is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

In order to absolutely position something inside a parent you need to use the position:relative attribute. Try the following CSS:

```
tr {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: -20;
}
```

Obviously you would need the img HTML inside the tr